# Handling string payloads from AWS IOT Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

My thing would publish string payload something like `"[v1:ThingName]"` to a topic (someTopic/**topic1**). And I have a rule applied in the rule engine to capture this topic and send to a Lambda function.

```
SELECT * FROM 'someTopic/+'
```

I want to send the **topic1** part which will be captured from Rule engine along with the payload. So it can be captured from topic(2).
How do I concatenate topic(2) with * in select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After so much of trial and error, figured that you cannot do it like that because payload is string.

But how I got away with this was using the encode function. Essentially I encode the whole payload into base64 as a json object and then have the topic(2) value as well.

So my Rule SQL query would like this.

```
SELECT encode(*, 'base64') as encode, topic(2) as topic FROM 'someTopic/+'
```

Subsequently you decode the payload in the Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add one answer for an **already** encoded base64 string from your "Thing".

In my example, the message contained an encoded base64 image from the ESP32-CAM. I was able to get my lambda function to trigger and have the correct encoding with the following rule:

```sql
SELECT decode(encode(*, 'base64'), 'base64') as base64Image
```

[Recommended from the AWS docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/binary-payloads.html)